# Where to learn more about "closing off spaces"

Tags: computational-geometry

Closing off spaces isn't even the right term and that's part of the problem. If a pair of scissors was cutting a path in a straight line from xy coordinate to xy coordinate how could i computationally find out when a closed path had been formed and then also as it continues to travel when any new closed paths had been formed possibly by just intersecting with the last closed form?

Is there a proper name for that or any coding libraries dedicated to that?

Sorry for the soft question if there's somewhere better to post this let me know.

Thanks